# in 1 function take 2 screenshots of different size images

Tags: swift, uiview

I want my swift code below to take 2 screenshots. One screen shot should be the entire view from the top to 20 percent and the other from 20 percent to 100 percent of the height. I created a image that displays what exactly I am looking for. The images should have different ratios. I dont really know what else to add.

```
var drawbox = Canvas()
 @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
 @objc func saving(){
     
            
            let vex = self.view.screenshot(for: drawbox.frame, clipToBounds: true)
            
            
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(vex, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
        }
    
extension UIView {
    /// Takes a screenshot of a UIView, with an option to clip to view bounds and place a waterwark image
    /// - Parameter rect: offset and size of the screenshot to take
    /// - Parameter clipToBounds: Bool to check where self.bounds and rect intersect and adjust size so there is no empty space
    /// - Parameter watermark: UIImage of the watermark to place on top
    func screenshot(for rect: CGRect, clipToBounds: Bool = true, with watermark: UIImage? = nil) -> UIImage {
        var imageRect = rect
        if clipToBounds {
            imageRect = bounds.intersection(rect)
        }
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: imageRect).image { _ in
            drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bounds.size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
            watermark?.draw(in: CGRect(origin: imageRect.origin, size: CGSize(width: 32, height: 32))) // update origin to place watermark where you want, with this update it will place it in top left or screenshot.
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split the image after saving it I use this function to split the image into two half you can change the ratio

```
     extension UIImage {
     
    func topHalf(pers:CGFloat)-> UIImage? {
        guard let image = cgImage?
            .cropping(to: CGRect(origin: .zero,
                    size: CGSize(width: size.width * scale,
                                 height: (size.height * scale) * pers )))
        else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: 1, orientation: imageOrientation)
    }
    func bottomHalf(pers:CGFloat)-> UIImage? {
        let scaledHight = (size.height * scale)
        guard let image = cgImage?
            .cropping(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,
                                                 y: scaledHight - (scaledHight * pers).rounded()),
                                 size: CGSize(width: size.width * scale,
                                              height: scaledHight)))
        else {
            
            print("Null")
            
            return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: image)
    }
    
    func save(_ name: String) {
//            let path: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
        let path = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path.path).appendingPathComponent(name)
        try! self.pngData()?.write(to: url)
            print("saved image at \(url)")
        }
}
```

you can use it like this

```
let vex = self.view.screenshot(for:  self.view.frame, clipToBounds: true)
            vex .save("full.png") 
            let top = vex.topHalf(pers: 0.2)
            top?.save("Top.png")
            let bottom = vex.bottomHalf(pers: 0.8)
            bottom?.save("bottom.png")
```

Comment: i dont know how to implement this code just coping it to the code does nothing.

Comment: after you call screenshot you can use this function to split it

Comment: So I call it here  let vex = self.view.screenshot(for: drawbox.frame, clipToBounds: true). I tried a couple of things top half is not recognizing.

Comment: this is close to working but your code does not crop the images to the requested amount. Also your code is cropping the right side of the image slightly.

Comment: the new edit has the amounts you want and fix the width issue